# Hurry up the garden path

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> Flowing unceasingly;
>   Eaters of dung;
>   A sort of affection;
>   Almost a quarter past one;
>   Take a bow for this.
>
> Found with vegetables;
>   On the front of trousers;
>   Done on Facebook;
>   One and only one;
>   Made up half of ones.

What funny saying is expressed by the above?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The saying is:

> [Time flies like an arrow; Fruit flies like a banana.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_flies_like_an_arrow;_fruit_flies_like_a_banana)

Which, from the title, is an example of:

> A [garden path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence) — "a grammatically correct sentence that starts in such a way that a reader's most likely interpretation will be incorrect". On top of that, the title is doubly thematic since the saying is about time flying ("hurry up") and flies/bananas ("the garden path").

Because:

> *Flowing unceasingly;* => **Time** (philosophically)
>  *Eaters of dung;* => **flies** (of the insect variety)
>  *A sort of affection;* => **like** (to be fond of someone)
>  *Almost a quarter past one;* => **an** (1:14 is almost 1:15, which via A1-Z26 gives AN)
>  *Take a bow for this.* => **arrow** (as in bow and arrow)
>  *Found with vegetables;* => **Fruit** (as in fruit and veg)
>  *On the front of trousers;* => **flies** (of the zipper variety)
>  *Done on Facebook;* => **like** ()
>  *One and only one;* => **a** (singular article)
>  *Made up half of ones.* => **banana** (half "a"s)

Comment: And of course it is a ROT13(tneqra cngu fragrapr).

Comment: You got it! Nice and quick :-) For line 4, think of what makes up the word.

Comment: a single n lol :P

Comment: For the title: "hurry" refers to the first part of the saying. For line 4: your explanation also works surprisingly well, but the intention was that *1:14* is almost a quarter past one. (Too much of a stretch?)

Comment: @rand - Perhaps a little, but given it's such a minor part, I'll let it slide. :P (updated)